Tag "Religion" can't apply
I was trying to tag a question on the site. This question was about parapsychology. Surprinsingly, there are no tags for that kind of questions.
On the site, a tag "religion" exists, and I guess it's related to that kind of phenomenon, but adding the tag "religion" here is a bit strange, as it's not about religion at all.
The "religion" tag description says it's about spirituality. If not tag "parapsychology" is added (despise the fact it would be useful I think to describe some questions), the nearest one is "religion", but a question could be about spirituality, how to mediate, or anything, and a "religion" tag being inappropritate on the question and the way it is asked.

Parapsychology is off-topic here (to the best of my knowledge at least).

I don't think the study of parapsychology phenomenon, to validate or invalidate them is always off-topic. For instance, the question I was about to tag was the scientific study of intuition, or telepathy, and the question was clearly accepted as no off-topic.

You might be right, ... as long as the question is looking for a scientific answer (thus likely disproving it, if it is truly parapsychology ;p). The point is that non-scientific discourse (as in answers) are off-topic here.

It's a topic studied by psychology, the TOOLS need to be scientific, I agree, but with scientific tools and methods, I think nothing is off-topic. Suggested that because it's a common field of study. The study of intuition and of telepathy is in this field. Even if you have a bogus topic, you need to study it with scientific tool to validate or invalidate it. That you mean is off-topic I think, is claim with no scientific tools, criticism or methods.
